# Why the method of separation of variables works?

Tags: mathematical-physics

The method of separation of variables is used in many occasions in the upper level physics courses such as QM and EM. But when it is used there is no clear reason why using it is permitted it except that it works, or that let us try and see.

Is there a theorem which provides the condition(s) that if satisfied then the method of separation of variables will be guaranteed to work in PDEs?

Comment: @ChrisWhite There are theoretical and mathematical physicists here who might know the answer to my question and who might not be following math stackexchange regularly. I want to maximize my chances to get an answer so I posted my question here and there. Sorry for offending anybody.